# Inserting data with mysql in scrapy

Tags: python, twisted, scrapy

This is my demo, I think there are no errors but this code can not insert data to mysql!?

setting.py

This is the setting code:

```
BOT_NAME = 'Scan'
SPIDER_MODULES = ['scan.spiders']
#NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'scan.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['scan.pipelines.MySQLStorePipeline']
```

This is the pipelines code, I think it contains no error:

pipelines.py

```
from scrapy import log
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline
import datetime
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors


class MySQLStorePipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.db = adbapi.ConnectionPool('MySQLdb',
            db = 'spider',
            host='localhost',
            user = 'root',
            passwd = '123456',
            cursorclass = MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor,
            charset = 'utf8',
            use_unicode = True
        )

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        query = self.db.runInteraction(self._conditional_insert, item)
        query.addErrback(self.handle_error)
        return item

    def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):
        if item.get('url'):
            tx.execute(\
                "insert into spider (url) "
                "values (%s)",(item['link'])
            )
            #log.msg("Item stored in db: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
    def handle_error(self, e):
        log.err(e)
```

This is the spider modules, I think it contains no errors!

spider.py

```
# coding=utf-8
from urlparse import urljoin
import simplejson

from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from scan.items import ScanItem

class ScanSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'Scan'
    allowed_domains = ["a.com"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.a.com",
    ]
    rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'http://(.*?)'),deny_domains=(r'qq.com'))
        ),
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'http://www.a.com')), callback="parse_item"),
        )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        item = ScanItem()
        items = []
        #item['title'] = hxs.select('//title/text()').extract()
        item['url'] = hxs.select('//a[@href]').re('(\"http://(.*?)\")').extract()
        items.append(item)
        return items
SPIDER = ScanSpider()
```

Comment: Can you provide a more concise code example?

Comment: When you run this - what's the debug output? (I would also suggest narrowing your post though... the community doesn't require most of that code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seriously needs to read out http://doc.scrapy.org , you are missing very basics .

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    item = ScanItem()
    items = []
    #item['title'] = hxs.select('//title/text()').extract()
    item['url'] = hxs.select('//a[@href]').re('(\"http://(.*?)\")').extract()
    items.append(item)
    return items
```

in your `parse_items` there is no need to add item in items of list you can simply return `item` like

```
    def parse_item(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       item = ScanItem()
       #item['title'] = hxs.select('//title/text()').extract()
       item['url'] = hxs.select('//a[@href]').re('(\"http://(.*?)\")').extract()
       return item
```

keeping in mind `item['url']` has a list of `urls`

in your `MySQLStorePipeline`

```
def _conditional_insert(self, tx, item):
    if item.get('url'):
        tx.execute(\
            "insert into spider (url) "
            "values (%s)",(item['link'])
        )
```

you are trying to insert `item['link']` in database while you never populated `item['link']` but only `item['url']`.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, without further clarification.

I think that since the return of a scrape is expected to be an `Item` (sub class thereof, or just even a `dict` - I will admit I haven't checked the code thoroughly to see how this *should* / *does* work), then:

```
item = ScanItem()
items = []
...
return items
```

Looks a little sus.

You need to do a little more analysis on your side though to get a meaningful/correct answer.